# getting black screen when app goes back to front

Tags: ios, view

I am using a map (not Google maps) on my view.
The app seems to work fine and all, but when it goes to background, I run other apps and after a while when I come back to my application, the app comes back with a black screen and doesn't seem to change.

What could be causing that ?
What can I do to prevent this ?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using some Web services calling?

Comment: Not really enough information to even guess. Standard debugging - put some log statements in - are you getting a memory warning? Something being nil'ed that shouldn't be? Happen every time?

Comment: I will check that memory warning ASAP, thanks!

Comment: Just what might need to be done if there IS a memory warning ?